# Magento2 parent-child theme configuration and deployment issues

Tags: configuration, themes, magento2

Having issues with site themes.
I have a parent theme and a child theme. Several files/layouts are overriden in the child theme.
This was all working fine up until yesterday or the day before (been working on a module, so only noticed the issue today).

The child theme static files are not being generated...only the requirejs-config.js file.
The parent theme static files are created fine.

If i switch to a default Magento theme (luma) for the store...keeping the parent theme set globally, i get the same result. The luma files only contain the JS file mentioned above.

If i change the global theme to luma, the old parent theme static files are still generated, and once again...only a JS file in the luma static files. (Why is it still generating the old parent theme static files, if it is not set for any website/store?)

```
- im in developer mode
- no themes in DB have the virtual setting (all are 0)
- All the right theme files are in place...this theme has been around for a while. its not brand new.
- i downloaded a fresh DB copy from the staging site (which is working fine) to ensure this wasnt an issue with data in my local DB
- Switched GIT branches to ensure none of my latest work had caused an issue
- There are 2 system configs for theme_id (global/websites). These are both set to theme id 2 at the moment (luma)
- All the usual CLI commands are being run each time i change something trying to figure this out. Its not a cache clean/flush/upgrade command running issue.
```

Questions:

```
1. How is it detecting and deploying the parent theme files...when all website/stores are set to luma theme?
2. Why aren't theme files no longer being deployed to pub/static...except the old parent theme files (even though i am in developer mode, and files don't need deploying....some files are always deployed, its not me running deployment commands)
3. What could possibly be involved in causing this issue, except the areas i mention above that ive been playing with?
```

Comment: Any status update on this?  How did you fix or workaround?